# How to Protect API routs : Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-5

How to make API routes only accessible inside the app?

For example `http://host.com/api/products` returns the data as intended but it's really insecure since anyone could access it through postman or the browser.

Comment: use auth for that

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport

Comment: Well, then you need to add some authentication. The "what exactly" would depend on details that you did not provide. For example, is the API call visible in browsers network traffic or is it for one backend system talking to another? Are you actually using full REST or is there a server-side session?  Things like that. We need more information.

Comment: Just like Akram recommended, you should use Laravel Passport. If you want to keep things super simple, use 'Personal Access Tokens'. I recommend you read first 'Installation' and 'Personal Access Tokens' sections in the docs to get started. If the API is just for you (i.e. you don't want to give API access to your users), you most likely won't have to implement the typical authorization redirect flow described in the other sections. It's quite unfortunate that the simplest implementation is described only towards the end of the documentation page.

Comment: @Amade Yes, I am using Passport for APIs which require user auth, but  what about those APIs which don't need API Auth like browsing categories, products ... in mobile app, after that when need to fill the cart as example, so he must login and continue the step using  laravel passport.

Comment: @AkramWahid, plz read my comment above.

Comment: I am talking about something like that https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard   but there is a problem to put the token statically in the headers, may be hacked and any one can steal the token.

Comment: @P. Dev You can decide whether the route requires authentication at the route level. For categories, products etc. maybe you just don't need authentication? In this case, you'd just skip the middleware('auth:api') part.